# Best Pratices: How to modify RestTemplate so if (response is 401 and url is in a certain API list) then auto call login?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, kotlin, resttemplate

I am writing a Spring application using Kotlin that has:

- API call is in 2 main **list** of API:

  - API belong to **internal system**: Automatic call login when response is **401 unauthorized**
  - API being called by **external service**: Return response with error message when **401 unauthorized**

Right now I'm using RestTemplate to call API, so my questions is **what is the best pratices to modify RestTemplate so if (response is 401 and url is in the second API list) then auto call login?**

Example of my code:

List API endpoints:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
class AppApiEnpoint(
        @Autowired
        private val appProperties: AppProperties
) {

    var orderCreateUrl: String = appProperties.getUrl("/order/create.json").toString()
}
```

API call

```
fun create(contentRequest: OrderSendAgentDto, accessToken: String): ResponseEntity<OrderResponseDto> {
    val requestUri = UrlBuilder(appApiEnpoint.orderCreateUrl).toString()

    val headers = HttpHeaders()
    headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED
    val body = HttpUtils.convertObject2Map(contentRequest)
    body.add("access_token", accessToken)
    val request = HttpEntity(body, headers)
    val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
    val response = restTemplate.postForEntity(requestUri, request, OrderResponseDto::class.java)

    return response
}
```

Note:

- I did come up with a way to wrap the response in a Util method to handle this logic but if so then there will be a lot of code that was used before that I have to fix and new APIs are constantly being added during development. This is not an suitable approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `ResponseErrorHandler` to the rest template that should do  auto-login, or even use @Retry with retry handlers on API methods that should do auto-login

Comment: But i only want some request with specific URL to auto-login. How can i do that?

Comment: you have the url in arguments of ResponseErrorHandler::handleError(URI url, HttpMethod method, ClientHttpResponse response)

Comment: Your solution work perfect! I want to ask you a small question: can i use both ResponseErrorHandler and ResponseEntityExceptionHandler? These various way to handle exception actually confuse me.